# Labelling a 100% Stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

How does one label a 100% stacked bar chart, like the one that follows, with appropriate values in the stack?

```
# dummy data
dat <- data.frame(
   Banner=c(rep("Company A",5),rep("Company B",5)), 
   Response=factor(c(1:5,1:5)), 
   Proportion=c(10,20,40,20,10,10,30,40,10,10))

dat <- rbind(dat,dat,dat)
dat$Time <- c(rep("Time 1",10),rep("Time 2",10),rep("Time 3",10))
```

I can get this to plot, without labels, no problem:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Banner, Proportion, fill=Response)) + 
   geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
   facet_grid(~Time)
```

[image: 100% stacked bar by two variables]

However, what I need to do is label each element, preferrably in the center of the element. I remember seeing a function using ddply (I think it was Ramnath's answer), but for the life of me I can't find it.

Something like:

```
dat <- ddply(dat, .(Banner, Time), function(x) {
   x$Pos <- cumsum(x$Proportion) # at top of element, want middle!
   x})
```

Comment: Brandon I think that's the post you're after.  If this isn't a duplicate my apologies.

Comment: Just add this: `+ geom_text(aes(label=Proportion, y = ave(Proportion, list(Banner, Time), FUN=function(x) cumsum(x) - .5*x)))`

Comment: Thanks Tyler! I was googling like a madman trying to find that post. Definitely a duplicate.